# where is the definition of "jiffies"? the "jiffies.h" only extern it

Tags: linux, definition, extern

I search the whole Linux-3.13 code, but I cant find the definition. Maybe this question is simple, but it puzzle me for long time. And I cant find the similar topic by Google :( , Can anyone tell me?

Thanks in advance!

---

Hi all, I find it.Which is defined in vmlinux.lds.S:

```
#ifndef __ARMEB__
jiffies = jiffies_64;
#else
jiffies = jiffies_64 + 4;
#endif
```

And jiffies_64 in timer.c:

```
u64 jiffies_64 __cacheline_aligned_in_smp = INITIAL_JIFFIES;
```

In a word, it's my careless! I chronically believe that ".global" is the syntax to define a variable, but I forgot this is ld script, it has another form. Thanks to you!

Comment: Do you mean the meaning of the word itself?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I believe the OP is asking about `extern unsigned long volatile jiffies;`

Comment: As Dai say, The jiffies.h extern the jiffies:                       "extern u64 __jiffy_data jiffies_64;
extern unsigned long volatile __jiffy_data jiffies"; I think it's not the definition of the jiffies variable, is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jiffy_%28time%29#Uses),

> Jiffy values for various Linux versions and platforms have typically varied between about 1 ms and 10 ms, with 10 ms reported as an increasingly more common standard in the [Jargon File](http://catb.org/~esr/jargon/html/J/jiffy.html).

You might check platform-specific configuration sources, it might be missing from a platform-independent repo.

Comment: Thanks Potatoswatter, following your point, I grep a SDK's build-path(after build in this path, the boot/uImage/rootfs are present), and can't find the jiffies definition yet. :-(.     when grep  I exclude the "driver" path, and all *.c source file, but I think it's ok.